# How to call onItemSelected programmatically?

Tags: android

After I made a call of notifyDataSetChanged, all my references from onItemSelected are outofdate.

e.g

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                onFront1 = (ImageView) view;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

getView

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

             imView = new ImageView(this.myContext);

            imView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            imView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                    onFront2 = view;
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }
            });
            onFront3 = imView;
            return imView;
        }
```

rotate

```
public void rotateS(View v) {
        ImageView iv = onFront;
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(geg);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
        geg = 90;
        Log.d("rorate", "yes");
    }
```

`onFront` references the old imageView, thus I cannot use it any more. How can I call onItemselected again?

A bit more detailed:

I am taking imageView and use it in `rotateS` function. It uses onFront but replace it with global variables onFront1|onFront2|onFront3
onFron1 allows rotate image as soon as it appears on screen, but became useless after notifydatasetChanged.
onFront2  is not affected by notifyDataSetChanged, but it works only after screen was taped ( prety logical)
onFront3 does not work at all.
What I want to achieve - hold reference to current imageview and update it as soon as imageview was updated.

Comment: Please, describe your scenario more clear. What are you trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: I updated question, can you revise you answer according to new update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to reassign `onFront` at the same code block, where you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

If somehow you cannot do it in your scenario, then you need additional mechanism to track payload inside your ListAdapter.

For example, you want to mark selected items with a specific color.
You can introduce a ItemData class:

```
public class ItemData{
    public bool IsSelected;
    // some other data if you need, maybe link to the image view
}
```

You ListAdapter should use a List of these objects (listData) and implement getItem() method:

```
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return this.listData.get(i);
}
```

When you select item - in the listener you call

```
((ItemData)parent.getItem(position)).IsSelected = true;
```

Then, if you add new item above previously selected, you also should add new item inside `listData`. The position of previously selected item will change, but the associated `ItemData` instance will not.

Comment: I tried ( maybe in wrong way) but (ImageView) view from getView and (ImageView) view from onItemSelected seems to be different